# HTML data-* tags in non HTML 5 document

Tags: html

I like the data-* tags concept.

Should i use it in non HTML 5 documents?
For example:

```
<li data-id="1001">Item A</li>
```

For indicating the inner application is (rather than the DOM id)

Comment: As far as I know you can use every tag attribute you want. Or it is not a valid html5 thing without the "data-" before? I am actually using and accessing idC="XX" in my website and never had any problem

Comment: The real question is why can't you use a HTML5 doctype? After Mathias' answer, it seems that's the only problem left.

Comment: If you want to use HTML 5 features, use an HTML 5 Doctype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference is that your document won’t validate as HTML 4.01 (or whatever non-HTML5 version you’d be using). Nothing would actually break; browsers won’t care.

Here’s a relevant quote by Paul Irish ([source](http://groups.google.com/group/html5boilerplate/browse_thread/thread/6d1b6b152aca8ed2)):

> The validator giving you errors doesn't mean browsers won't render
>   your page  as well as they can. In fact, what the validator thinks of
>   your markup is  very very different from what a browser thinks of it.
>
> In fact, it's more  like a browser is your friend who is super
>   flexible, even when you were late  to hanging out with him and
>   everything you say to him sounds like a jumbled  mess... He'll totally
>   understand and be as accommodating with your  imperfections as
>   possible.
>
> Mrs Validator, on the other hand, will mark up your papers
>   with red pen  again and again. Yes your thesis is perfect and it's
>   supported with  paragraphs of justification masterfully. Such prose,
>   such rhetoric! But no  you forgot a comma and your "who" should be a
>   "whom" and that semicolon  absolutely should be an em-dash. Do it
>   again!  Meanie. :(
>
> Validation can be a useful tool to make sure you
>   haven't made any egregious  errors. But don't treat 100% valid markup
>   as a goal. There are plenty of  extremely well justified decisions you
>   can make in your markup that will not  validate, like the
>   X-UA-Compatible meta tag.  For more thoughts on  validation, I
>   certainly recommend Nicholas Zakas's post: 
>   http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/08/17/the-value-of-html-validation/
>
> PS. as an example of how browsers are super accommodating.. You can
>   use all  sorts of HTML5 features even with an XHTML 1.0 Strict
>   doctype. Browsers  don't really give a shit. They make it work.

Comment: I know that it works,but should i use it or not?
What is the alternative? to give it 'id="menu1001"' and parse it?

Comment: You should not worry about validation too much. In this case, you know what you’re doing, and it’s valid in HTML5; so there’s no good reason not to use it. (OTOH, why not just use HTML5?)

Comment: A class would likely be easier than using an `id`.

Comment: But a different class for every item feels like "manipulating" the system

Comment: @uriz Updated my answer, adding a relevant quote on the importance of HTML validation.